# Recursion and Exceptions in Python, how to catch exceptions without losing recursive stack

Tags: python, exception, recursion

I have code that's recursively looking through a json hierarchy to find actions that may be nested in an arbitrary amount of flow control blocks. The following code gets most of the work done. However, it seems like it hops all the way out of the recursive stack when it hits a key it doesn't know how to handle and thus I miss important data. I want it to just continue at the current recursion level, how do I do that?

Apologies for the debug printing. If someone would like to look at sample debug output where this issue occurs, just ask in the comments and I'll include it.

```
def getActionList(dict, parentKey, clarityOffset):
    actions = []
    print(clarityOffset + str(len(dict.items())) + ' values in dict')
    i = 0
    for key, val in dict.items():
        print(clarityOffset + 'considering ' + str(i) +' -ith Key: ' + key)
        #only go down the recursion tree for 'action container' keys.  
        if any(key.find(k) != -1 for k in kRelevantKeys):
            print(clarityOffset + 'Key is a flow key, hopping down the tree')
            try:
                actions = actions + getActionList(val, key, clarityOffset + '    ')
            except:
                continue
        #Some If's and foreaches are named specific things, check type here for those
        elif any(val['type'].find(f) != -1 for f in kFlowTypes):
            print(clarityOffset + 'Key has a flow type, hopping down the tree')
            try:
                actions = actions + getActionList(val, key, clarityOffset + '    ')
            except: 
                continue
        elif parentKey == 'actions' or parentKey == '':
            print(clarityOffset + 'Is an action, key is ' + key)
            actions.append((key, val))
        i += 1

    print(clarityOffset + 'All actions are....')
    for action in actions:
        print(clarityOffset + action[0])
    return actions
```

Comment: `except: continue` is a really bad way to deal with keys you don't know how to handle. It could be hiding all sorts of bugs you don't see because you just `continue`d on every exception.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really get to the core of the question being asked, but I was able to get the functionality I wanted by changing the code to the following...

```
def getActionList(jsonDict, parentKey, clarityOffset):
    actions = []

    for key, val in jsonDict.items():
        if not isinstance(val, dict):
            continue

        #only go down the recursion tree for 'action container' keys.  
        if any(key.find(k) != -1 for k in kRelevantKeys):
            actions = actions + getActionList(val, key, clarityOffset + '    ')
        #Some If's and foreaches are named specific things, check type here for those
        elif 'type' in val and any(val['type'].find(f) != -1 for f in kFlowTypes):
            actions = actions + getActionList(val, key, clarityOffset + '    ')
        elif parentKey == 'actions' or parentKey == '':
            actions.append((key, val))

    return actions
```